# How to make this object.runtimestyle.filter='Gray' for supporting in firefoxbrowser for apply gray scale?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I am try for `object.runtimestyle.filter='Gray'` for gray scale and `object.runtimestyle.filter='Invert'` for invert color. These things are working fine in IE, but firefox. Can u make it by using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting article here: 
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/grayscaling-in-non-ie-browsers/

With Demo Source here: 
http://james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale/grayscale.js/view/

Comment: Its good for images, but i need it for whole div. I am using more than one images and also labels, text and HTML controls in inside the div. can u make  some other things?

Comment: That example included functions for looping all tags by tag name.

Answer (score 0):

check  [this library](http://snipplr.com/view/2836/grayscale-img-with-css-crossbrowser/) and you can try it out with some examples in their [lab](http://www.netzgesta.de/lab/), also another good example [here](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/grayscaling-in-non-ie-browsers/)

Comment: Its good for images, but i need it for whole div. I am using more than one images and also labels, text and HTML controls in inside the div. can u make some other things?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're asking about images, I recommend using the [Pixastic JavaScript library](http://www.pixastic.com/).

[Desaturate](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/desaturate/) can make an image grayscale, and [Invert](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/invert/) can.. invert it.